Barcode/strip plot in power bi
I have a visual on Tableau which shows purchases per every user over time. Here every row is user_id (X axis), every orange spot is a purchase and in Y axis is dates of purchases.
Tableau visual here
I need to make similar to this visual to PowerBI. Any help please?
I have tried matrix which seems that seems it would work but the widths of columns has to be as small as possible to be able to see whole timeline at once (without scrolling to the right) and I couldn't achieve that.
After the comment from @DavideBecci I have tried Deneb-viz approach but the view is far from what I try to achieve

This is a barcode plot (a density plot is something different). This is simple to create using Deneb and Vega: https://deneb-viz.github.io/

Thank you for correcting me @davidebacci ; I have checked Deneb-viz but it's still far from what im trying to do. I have updated the question.
